# generics don't seem to be taken fully into account in typescript function

Tags: typescript

I have the following setup:

```
export const doQuery = <DocType>({ query }: { query: Query<DocType> }) => {
  return query.doTheQuery()
}
```

When I go to use it:

```
export const CollectionCount = ({ docType }: { docType: DocTypeKeys }) => {
  const query = createQuery(docType)
  
  return doQuery({ query })
}
```

DocType can be `A`, `B` or `C`. However I'm getting an error on `query` within `doQuery`:

```
Type 'Query<A> | Query<B> | Query<C>' is not assignable to type 'Query<A>'
```

I'm confused how typescript is thinking that query can only be `Query<A>` in this case

Comment: Please make your question a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here, each with its own benefits and drawbacks. First:

```
const doQuery = <D extends A | B | C, T extends Query<D>>({ query }: { query: T }): D => {
  return query.doTheQuery()
}
```

Good thing about it - type safety inside doQuery implementation. Bad thing, it has its type glitches when you use it.

```
function foo(q: Query<A>): A {
    const a = doQuery({query: q}); // Bad: "a" is typed to A | B | C
    const a1: A = a; // Error because A | B | C can not be assigned to A

    const b: B = doQuery({query: q}) // Good: it errors in incompatible query

    const c: A = doQuery({query: q}) // Good: it assignes without typecasting to the correct type
    const c1: A = c // No error
}
```

Other option is to type it like that

```
const doQuery = <T extends Query<any>>({ query }: { query: T }): T extends Query<infer V> ? V : never => {
  return query.doTheQuery()
}
```

Good: it has the best declaration in terms of usage (like option 3). It always has correct return type. Bad: you should be careful inside the implementation.

```
const doQuery = <T extends Query<any>>({ query }: { query: T }): T extends Query<infer V> ? V : never => {
  const result = query.doTheQuery()

  const a = 6 + result; // No error, because "result" on this step inferred as "any"

  return result;
}
```

And finally, here is my favorite one:

```
type DoQueryResult<T extends Query<A | B | C>> = T extends Query<infer V> ? V : never;

const doQuery = <T extends Query<A | B | C>>({ query }: { query: T }): DoQueryResult<T> => {
  return result as DoQueryResult<T>;
}
```

It has all benefits of the previous two solutions and just one drawback: you should typecast return statement in implementation (`result as DoQueryResult<T>`)

```
const doQuery = <T extends Query<A | B | C>>({ query }: { query: T }): DoQueryResult<T> => {
  const result = query.doTheQuery()

  const a = 6 + result; // It errors

  return result as DoQueryResult<T>; // It infers result as A | B | C and we need to typecast it
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use the given type (A, B or C) within `doQuery` or is it stuck within the `Query<>`?

Comment: @ChrisDrackett Could you please explain a little more what do you mean, what you want to achieve?

Comment: basically the return value of `doQuery` is an array of `A` `B` or `C`, so I'm trying to figure out how to work that into your final answer above

Comment: @ChrisDrackett There are three solutions in the answer. First one gives you `A | B | C` without additional help from you side, but, it gives you correct type if you assign it to the variable with this type (and prevents you from assignment to incorrect type, see `listing 2`). Second and third solutions always give you correct output type (they give you  `A` for `Query<A>`, `B` for `Query<B>`, etc). I would prefer third solution (`listing 5`), but it is up to you which to choose based on their advantages and drawbacks.